# Calculation of certain limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha>0$ and $t \in R$. Can any one calculate the following limits:

a)  $$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac{n+1}{k}\right)^{\alpha} \sin\left(t\ln \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)\right);$$

b)  $$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\left(\frac{n+1}{k}\right)^{\alpha} \sin\left(t\ln \left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)\right);$$

Comment: If $\alpha>1$ then these  limits are not  zero.